# jQuery click function doesn't work in mobile browser

Tags: jquery

So i've got problem with mobile clicks. So i want to make script click and open the gallery, when i press on button.

```
<script>
jQuery(".button-class").click(function(){
  jQuery(".gallery-with-images-class").click(); * mobile click like this
    });
</script>
```

This unfortunately doesn't work on mobile browser. I know about touchstart and touchend, but how to do this like a "Click" option - not an event handler

Comment: 'click' **is** an event handler.  It's a wrapper around `on('click', ...)`

Comment: It works fine in desktop browser

Comment: Because your mouse will do a click.  Touch devices do not necessarily "click", which is why you have to also bind and handle for the touch events.  My first comment was in reference to your *like a "Click" option - not an event handler* statement.  They are all event handlers.

Comment: try `jQuery(".gallery-with-images-class").get(0).click();` - I think the click action is on native js object and not jquery object.   But if all your click is doing is clicking another element, why not just add both classes to the same click event handler

Comment: @Taplar I'm pretty sure that mobile browsers automatically translate touch events to the equivalent clicks, they don't require every web site to add explicit code for this.

Comment: I just tested this https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/nssgh7dw/ in Mobile Chrome, and clicking on Button successfully triggered the event on Gallery.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @barmar Yep, it work's fine on "jsfiddle". But on my wordpress site it doesn't (jQuery is installed)

Comment: If you can't provide something reproducible, it's going to be hard to get an answer. How are we supposed to know what else is going on on your site that might be interfering.

Comment: Where is the problem specifically? Is the problem with the click handler on `.button-class`, or the click on `.gallery-with-images-class`? Put alerts in each, and tell is which alerts fail?

Answer (score 0):

try `.trigger` which is the same really...

```
<script>
  jQuery(".button-class").click(function(){
    jQuery(".gallery-with-images-class").trigger('click');
  });
</script>
```

if not, any better with vanilla js?

```
<script>
  document.querySelector(".button-class").addEventListener('click', function () {
   var el = document.querySelector(".gallery-with-images-class")
   (el.onclick || el.click || function() {})()
  })
</script>
```

or lastly, just hook into all events that the mobile would use

```
<script>
  jQuery(".button-class").on('click touchstart', function () {
    // some code here
  })

// orr
  jQuery(".button-class").on('click touch', function () {
    // some code here
  })
</script>
```

Comment: The nested one is not an event handler, it's triggering another event.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mobile browsers automatically translate touch events to click, you don't need to code this explicitly.

Comment: I can't even reproduce his problem, see the fiddle I put in a comment above.

Comment: @Bramar... depends on the element and the browser. I have on occasion had to add `touchstart` in addition to click. I don't recall but i think it is for elements that aren't necessarily clickable like a `button` or `a`, etc. This isn't across the board though. Its only some browsers IIRC, but adding it for everything did not cause issue.